# Creating a percentage bar plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, percentage

So I am just messing around with the titanic data set.
`

```
options(digits = 3)    # report 3 significant digits
library(tidyverse)
library(titanic)

titanic <- titanic_train %>%
  select(Survived, Pclass, Sex, Age, SibSp, Parch, Fare) %>%
  mutate(Survived = factor(Survived),
         Pclass = factor(Pclass),
         Sex = factor(Sex))
```

`

Now I wanted to make a barplot that shows the three different Pclasses on the x-axis, and per Pclass a side-by-side bar for women and men. Kinda like this:
`

```
titanic %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Pclass, fill=Sex)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge())
```

`

But instead of the count of men and women in those classes, I want it to display the percentage of them that survived. I've been messing around with this for a while now and can't get it to work. The closest I got was to add this to the aes:
`y=(titanic$Survived/(..count..))*100`

But this takes the total number of survivors and divides them by the filtered passengers. What I need is the survivors per category (class 1, female / class 1, male / class 2, female / etc.) and divide this by the "..count..". Is there a way to do this? Please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

There are several options to achieve your desired result.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(titanic)
library(GGally)
```

##### Option 1: Use `GGAlly::stat_prop`

If you are looking for an out-of-the-box option then you could use `GGAlly::stat_prop` which adds a `by` aesthetic which could be used to set the denominator for computing proportions.

```
titanic %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Pclass, y = after_stat(prop), fill = Sex, by = Pclass)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(), stat = "prop") +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(100 * after_stat(prop))),
    position = position_dodge(.9), stat = "prop", vjust = -.2
  )
```

[image]

##### Option 2: Compute the percentages manually

A second and easy option would be to compute the counts and the proportions manually outside of `ggplot()`.

```
titanic %>%
  count(Pclass, Sex) %>% 
  group_by(Pclass) %>%
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Pclass, y = prop, fill = Sex)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(100 * prop)),
            position = position_dodge(.9), vjust = -.2
  )
```

[image]

##### Option 3: Compute the percentages on the fly

Finally, the third option would be to compute the percentages on the fly which requires to compute the percentages per `x` axis category for which I use `ave()`. In some sense this is an implementation of what `GGAlly::stat_prop` offers out of the box:

```r
titanic %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Pclass, y = after_stat(ave(count, x, FUN = function(x) x / sum(x))), fill = Sex)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = after_stat(round(100 * ave(count, x, FUN = function(x) x / sum(x))))),
            position = position_dodge(.9), vjust = -.2, stat = "count"
  )
```

[image]

**UPDATE** To get the proportion who survived I would go for option 2, i.e. compute the counts and percentages manually:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(titanic)

titanic %>%
  count(Pclass, Sex, Survived) %>% 
  group_by(Sex, Pclass) %>%
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n)) %>%
  filter(Survived == 1)  %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Pclass, y = prop, fill = Sex)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(100 * prop)),
            position = position_dodge(.9), vjust = -.2
  ) +
  labs(y = "% Survived")
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Stefan, thank you for these option. I did indeed not know about these, but if I look at your graphs, I realise that I must've explained my desired graph wrong. I want it to show women in class 1 who survived as percentage of the total women in class 1. Same for the men, and then the same for the other classes.

Comment: Haha. At a second glance I got it. See my update where I opted for option 2. IMHO the easiest approach to achieve your desired result.

Comment: Sweet. That's exactly it!! Thanks!