# How to transform the Y axis scale from count to percentage?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/metea.png)

```
 promo_df %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x=Promo_Type, y= `Total responses`, group= as.factor(`Response Type`), fill= `Response Type`)) +
geom_col(stat="count",position = "dodge") + 
facet_wrap(~Promo_for,scales = "free_x") + 
theme_bw() + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30,hjust=1))  +
labs(x="Promotional Category", y="Customer Response",title = "Distribution of Feedback Across Diverse Tire Promotions")
```

I tried altering the y-axis scale to percent using `scale_y_continous(labels = scales::percent_format())`. It worked and changed the scale to percent , however the percentage are not summing to 100%.

Comment: Welcome to SO! As your data reflects the counts, simply changing the axis labels to percentages will not give you the correct values. Instead I would suggest to compute the percentages manually outside of ggplot. See [ggplot replace count with percentage in geom_bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776200/ggplot-replace-count-with-percentage-in-geom-bar) or [Creating a percentage bar plot in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74856194/creating-a-percentage-bar-plot-in-ggplot2)

Comment: Plot (counts divided by total ) times 100.

Comment: How do you want to normalise your percentages? Should they be relative to the total count or the count broken down by `Promo_for`?

If you could include the output from `head(promo_df)` it would be helpful in providing a response too.